# image capture app crashes on pressing back button

Tags: android, android-camera

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 2500;
Button Report_help;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Report_help=(Button)findViewById(R.id.report_help);
    Report_help.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
             startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
        }
    });

}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
          Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
          ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.display_image);
          imageview.setImageBitmap(image);
    }
}

}
```

This app captures the image and displays in the imageview.But the problem is after I capture the image and press the back button app crashes.I don't know why is this so? Please anyone help.

Comment: post your onPause method, and also the errors showed in LogCat when it crashes

Comment: can you post your logcat?

Comment: Do you want to manage your back key pro grammatically ?

Comment: I am not able to get the logacat results since my phone doesn't get detected in my system.So to check the app i have to install everytime

Comment: maybe programatically something wud help

Comment: you are checked  if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST)  if you have pressed the ok button after your picture is taken and you have previewed. like that check if  if (requestCode !=CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) simply finish or show some alrert.

Comment: press back button will not return bitmap and will cause nullpointerexception~ you can avoid it by checking if the resultCode is Activity.OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you press back button

```
Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

in onActivityResult cause the **Null pointer exception** error, please catch this one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to check that case.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Uri selectedImageUri = null;
    String filePath = null;
    switch (requestCode) {                
            case PICK_Camera_IMAGE:
                 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    //use imageUri here to access the image                

                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                 break;
        }
```

hope this helps you.