# While selecting an image the app restarts on S3

Tags: android, file-upload, upload, webview, android-webview

I am developing an app that need to upload images to the server using WebView. But when user clicks on File Chooser button and selects Gallery or Camera to select the photo. My app restarts.

This is surely a memory issue, because if I restart my mobile phone, it starts working fine.

This issue is only seen on S3 and a few other devices. On most of the devices it works fine.

**Edit:**
The issue is not related to the IMAGE SIZE. Even if I choose the gallery to select the image and when the gallery opens I just click back button to go back to the app and the app restarts.

That means it has nothing to do with the image size. When the gallery opens in full screen and my app goes to background, Android kills my app because of low memory or something like that. But I don't know how to handle it.

---

i am saving my webview state and restoring it....but its not helping

Comment: I have observed memory issues on s3 having jellybean too, but that was when I select or take an image from gallery or camera respectively. Make sure you are re-sizing the bitmap that you get from the gallery. Also, **paste your logcat output**, that would help in solving your problem out here.

Comment: I've updated my OP, please take a look at the edit

Comment: @user1994990 Please post the logcat output that you are getting at crash, as I mentioned earlier in comment.

Comment: `or something like that` isn't particularly helpful error message when it comes to diagnosing the issue.  Can you please update your question with some more details?

Comment: this issue never comes to me but coming to client`s phone i have galaxy tab 2 and its work perfect on it..and it is not crashing it just restart the activity...thatswhy i cant provide the stacktrace or logcat

Comment: i can provide log which is on my tab is this help full?

Answer (score 0):

It's normal for the system to terminate your activities. What you can and should do is to write your app so that it can restore its state correctly. See the Android documentation [Recreacting an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It is tough to say what should be causing the error, as you are unable to post your logcat output. However, here are a few answers to the similar issue, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16399198/2003486) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9143593/2003486), and see if you are able to solve your issue.

Comment: Well, then I think you better get the log from your client or test it on the same device as your client's and get the log. Only then you will be able to understand the issue.